# Un-initialized final local variable vs un-initialized final instance variable

Tags: java, declaration, keyword, final

As per my knowledge, final variables must/can be initialized only once otherwise compiler is supposed to throw an error.

If the final instance variable `x` is not initialized an error is thrown but I faced no error when the local variable `y` is kept uninitialized in the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test
{
 final int x = 5;// if final variable x uninitialized, compilation error occurs
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     final int y;   // y is not initialized, **no error is thrown** 
     System.out.println("test program");
 }
}
```

Comment: yes you were rite at your place but you initialize two different variable. if you init one and only variable tow times at that time it throws the error.

Comment: Compiler will not throw error for uninitialized final variable, because you can initialize it later. Try final int y=1; y=2; then you will get error

Comment: @fastcodejava That has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
public class test
{
 final int x = 5;
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     final int y;
     System.out.println("test program");
     y=6;
     y=7;   
 }
}
```

`y=7` will give error:`The final local variable y may already have been assigned`. Since it is a `final` variable, and it has been assigned to `6`.

IMHO, a `final` local variable means once assigned, it cannot be re-assigned. But by `final int y` you are only declaring a `final` variable without assignment(initialization), which is legal in Java.(But in order to use it you still have to initialize it, or an error occurs.)

**Update:**

As commented below, you have noticed the difference between a `class field` final variable and a `local` final variable.

From Java Language Specification:

1. a `final field` must be `definely assigned` in the `static initializer` or the `constructor`:

   > 8.3.1.2 final Fields
   >   A field can be declared final (§4.12.4). Both class and instance variables (static
   >   and non-static fields) may be declared final.
   >   A blank final class variable must be definitely assigned by a static initializer of
   >   the class in which it is declared, or a compile-time error occurs (§8.7, §16.8).
   >   A blank final instance variable must be definitely assigned at the end of every
   >   constructor of the class in which it is declared, or a compile-time error occurs (§8.8,
   >   §16.9).

(Note that a non-final field can be left un-initialized)

2.A local variable(whether final or not) must be explicitly given a value before it is used:(**chapter 4.12.5,P88**)

> • A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value before it is
>   used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be
>   verified using the rules for definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

Comment: But I will get an error if 'x' is not initialized.

Comment: No, you will not. You can check below code: `final int x;
 
 public test() {
  x=1;
  x=2;
 }`

Comment: I meant, if i don't initialize 'x' at all not even in the constructor then I will get an error but same error will not be there if 'y' is uninitialized in the whole program.

Comment: see my update for the  reason.

Comment: You can easily prove that an uninitialized local `final` variable is unused, as its scope is limited to the method in which it has been declared. In contrast, you can not prove whether an instance field is unused by the entire application, especially not in a programming language supporting Reflection.

Answer (score 5):

The local variable isn't used and therefore can be left uninitialized

You will get compile error when try to use it (even if it's not `final`):

```
 System.out.println("test program" + y);
```

> The local variable y may not have been initialized

Answer (score 4):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) does not state that a `final` variable *must* be assigned (emphasis mine):

> A `final` variable **may** only be assigned to once.

And:

> A *blank `final`* is a final variable whose declaration lacks an initializer.

So your `y` variable is a *blank `final`*, and since it's not referenced anywhere further in your code, it's perfectly fine to leave it unassigned.

Answer (score 1):

As per the definition of a final variable, they can be initialized only once. In your code, you haven't initialized 'y' and you're not using it anywhere as well.

But if you do the following,

```
final int y;
System.out.println(y);
```

you will get 'variable y might not have been initialized'

Answer (score 1):

You will get an error when you try to use the declared final variable.

```
System.out.println(y);
```